# How to create complex moving/touchable animations in Android Studio?

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es

Does someone know how to do complex animations in Android Stuido such as [Select-Seats-Payment Animation](https://dribbble.com/shots/3646214-Select-Seats-Payment-flow)?

I know there is Open GL for creating Spirtes and so on but do you actually do this kind of complex animations with Open Gl? And also wouldn't that be laggy?

Any hints would be very appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: For CG in Android, there is nothing faster and OpenGL. You can do any animation using OpenGL, and it must not be laggy for them. However, you wouldn't like to use OpenGL if you learned this. It is a very low level graphics library so you have to code everything you need. Don't go the way if you are not familiar with Graphics Math or its Pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to create the flight zoom and rotate animation.You don't need to go to OpenGl level. You just need to learn canvas. All the seats and the flight itself is simply plain design. So no need for bitmaps/images to create them. Create all seats by drawing them and treat them as like separate objects and give them their own properties like click listeners(Clicks should be handled by onTouch() function of the customView). But it takes lots of practice in canvas API of Android.